# XSLT - Update namespaces of the original xml before applying other templates

Tags: xslt

I have an xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mdb:MD_Metadata xmlns:mdb="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/1.0"
   xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0"
   xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0"
   xmlns:mcc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"  
   xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0">
   <mdb:metadataIdentifier>
       <mcc:MD_Identifier>
           <mcc:authority>
               <cit:CI_Citation>
                   <cit:title>
                       <gco:CharacterString>Old UUID</gco:CharacterString>
                   </cit:title>
               </cit:CI_Citation>
           </mcc:authority>
           <mcc:code>
               <gco:CharacterString>3796749d-c8a5-46ae-af11-24a977cb1d9a</gco:CharacterString>
           </mcc:code>
           <mcc:codeSpace>
               <gco:CharacterString>urn:uuid</gco:CharacterString>
           </mcc:codeSpace>
       </mcc:MD_Identifier>
   </mdb:metadataIdentifier>
</mdb:MD_Metadata>
```

I want to update the namespaces (mdb and cit to2.0) before applying other templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:cit1="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0"
        xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0"
        xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0"
        xmlns:mcc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"
        xmlns:mco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mco/1.0"
        xmlns:mda="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mda/1.0"
        xmlns:mdb1="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/1.0"
        xmlns:mdb="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/2.0"
        xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
        xmlns:gcx="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gcx/1.0"
        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
 
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:template match="mdb1:*">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/2.0">
                <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::*) = 0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="add-iso19115-3.2018-namespaces"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="cit1:*" >
            <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
        

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:template>


    <!--Identity template that will copy every attribute, element, comment, and processing instruction to the output-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="mdb:MD_Metadata" mode="main">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
                <!-- add mdb:defaultLocale after mdb:metadataIdentifier -->
                <mdb:defaultLocale>
                    <lan:PT_Locale id="EN">
                        <lan:language>
                            <lan:LanguageCode codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" codeListValue="eng"/>
                        </lan:language>
                        <lan:characterEncoding>
                            <lan:MD_CharacterSetCode codeList="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_CharacterSetCode" codeListValue="utf8"/>
                        </lan:characterEncoding>
                    </lan:PT_Locale>
                </mdb:defaultLocale>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    
        <!-- replace cit:title -->
        <xsl:template match="mdb:metadataIdentifier/mcc:MD_Identifier/mcc:authority/cit:CI_Citation/cit:title/gco:CharacterString/text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="'UUID Test'"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- add mcc:description -->
        <xsl:template match="mdb:metadataIdentifier/mcc:MD_Identifier">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <mcc:description>
                <gco:CharacterString>Data was submitted
                </gco:CharacterString>
            </mcc:description>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- update attribute 'codeLIst' value of  mdb:metadataScope > mdb:MD_MetadataScope > mdb:resourceScope > mcc:MD_ScopeCode -->
        <xsl:template match="mdb:metadataScope/mdb:MD_MetadataScope/mdb:resourceScope/mcc:MD_ScopeCode">
            <xsl:if test="@codeListValue">
                <xsl:attribute name="codeList">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'https://schemas.isotc211.org/19115/resources/Codelist/cat/codelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode'" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="add-iso19115-3.2018-namespaces">
        <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="cit" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="lan" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="mcc" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="gco" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="xlink" select="'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet above only work if the namespaces associated with mdb and cit in the original file are as below:

```
<mdb:MD_Metadata xmlns:mdb="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/2.0"
    xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0"
    xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0"
    xmlns:mcc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"  
    xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0">
....
```

How can I first update the namespaces and then apply the rest templates against the updated xml?

Comment: Why that need to do the namespace change "before" the other change? If you need to change a namespace or even more that means transforming any nodes in the original namespace(s) so it might be a lot easier to do namespace changes and the other changes in one transformation step, just match your other templates on the original input namespaces. Otherwise you would need to use modes and have two steps in one stylesheet, store the result of the namespace transformation in a variable and push that to the second mode doing the other changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following is what you want, performing the namespace transformations and the other changes in one transformation step:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:cit1="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/1.0"
        xmlns:cit="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0"
        xmlns:lan="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0"
        xmlns:mcc="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"
        xmlns:mco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mco/1.0"
        xmlns:mda="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mda/1.0"
        xmlns:mdb1="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/1.0"
        xmlns:mdb="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mdb/2.0"
        xmlns:gco="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0"
        xmlns:gcx="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gcx/1.0"
        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
    <!--Identity template that will copy every attribute, element, comment, and processing instruction to the output-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 
  <xsl:template match="/mdb1:*">
    <xsl:element name="mdb:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:call-template name="add-iso19115-3.2018-namespaces"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template> 
  
  <xsl:template match="mdb1:*">
    <xsl:element name="mdb:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="cit1:*">
    <xsl:element name="cit:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
       <xsl:template match="mdb1:MD_Metadata">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
                <!-- add mdb:defaultLocale after mdb:metadataIdentifier -->
                <mdb:defaultLocale>
                    <lan:PT_Locale id="EN">
                        <lan:language>
                            <lan:LanguageCode codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" codeListValue="eng"/>
                        </lan:language>
                        <lan:characterEncoding>
                            <lan:MD_CharacterSetCode codeList="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_CharacterSetCode" codeListValue="utf8"/>
                        </lan:characterEncoding>
                    </lan:PT_Locale>
                </mdb:defaultLocale>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    
        <!-- replace cit:title -->
        <xsl:template match="mdb1:metadataIdentifier/mcc:MD_Identifier/mcc:authority/cit1:CI_Citation/cit1:title/gco:CharacterString/text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="'UUID Test'"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- add mcc:description -->
        <xsl:template match="mdb1:metadataIdentifier/mcc:MD_Identifier">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <mcc:description>
                <gco:CharacterString>Data was submitted
                </gco:CharacterString>
            </mcc:description>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- update attribute 'codeLIst' value of  mdb:metadataScope > mdb:MD_MetadataScope > mdb:resourceScope > mcc:MD_ScopeCode -->
        <xsl:template match="mdb1:metadataScope/mdb1:MD_MetadataScope/mdb1:resourceScope/mcc:MD_ScopeCode">
            <xsl:if test="@codeListValue">
                <xsl:attribute name="codeList">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'https://schemas.isotc211.org/19115/resources/Codelist/cat/codelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode'" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="add-iso19115-3.2018-namespaces">
        <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="cit" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/cit/2.0'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="lan" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="mcc" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="gco" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/-3/gco/1.0'"/>
        <xsl:namespace name="xlink" select="'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'"/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```